# Как в django реализовать отправку изображений с сервера клиенту и обратно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, django, сервер

Делаю декстопное приложение с сервером на django. Нужно реализовать отправку фотографий туда и обратно.
Изначально есть картинка на сервере в папке templates которая идет дефолтной при создании аккаунта.Я его поместил в бд так:

```
image = models.ImageField(default='Game_bunker.templates.users.def_prof_img.png', null=True, verbose_name='image')
```

Еще вопрос что хранит сам ImageField?Картинку или ссылку к нему?

Comment: ImageField хранит в базе строку, которая является одновременно путём к файлу относительно папки MEDIA_ROOT и ссылкой на него относительно адреса MEDIA_URL. При этом Django не занимается раздачей файлов, и вам нужно настроить свой основной веб-сервер так, чтобы он по адресу MEDIA_URL раздавал файлы из папки MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: Вот у меня есть картинка на стороне сервера и путь к нему. Как мне его передать клиенту?Просто вернуть ему ссылку на картинку или что? И как мне например доставать путь к файлу через image?

Comment: Настроить веб-сервер на раздачу файлов и попросить клиента запросить файл по ссылке у этого веб-сервера. К Django это не имеет отношения

Comment: Django всего лишь возвращает ссылку на картинку и больше ничего не делает, да

Comment: А как со стороны клиента отправлять изображения в сервер, чтобы они там хранились?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: У меня не веб-приложение,а декстопное.Запросы на сервер отправляю через requests.

Comment: Тогда при чём тут Django?

Comment: Так у меня вопрос был со стороны севера как картинкы оптравлять это я понял и как со стороны клиента.Еще как мне вытаскивать путь к файлу с ImageField. Может какая функция у него есть?

Comment: Это два совершенно не связанных вопроса, значит создавайте второй вопрос